# read multiple files in from a directoryusing matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

How can read multiple files in from a directory using matlab? Can someone please help correct my code below:

```
files =dir(fullfile(directory_path,'*.dat'));
numfiles = length('*.dat');
mydat = cell(1, numfiles);

for k = 1:numfiles
    mydata{k} = fopen([directory_path,files(k).name]);
    values=textscan(mydata{k},'%s','delimiter','\n');
    fclose(fid);
    %fprintf(values)
    ....do something with values.....

end
```

.dat files are just many rows and single column of strings that need to be read in a loop and processed further.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Zizy Archer.

I solved the problem this way:

```
files =dir(fullfile(directory_path,'*.dat'));
numfiles = length(files);

for k = 1:numfiles
    textFileName = [directory_path,files(k).name]
    fid = fopen(textFileName, 'r');
    textData = textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter','\n');
    fclose(fid);

    data = textData{:,1}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` gives file pointer, which you save to `mydata{k}`, and try to release by `fclose(fid)`. There is no `fid`, so it doesn't work.
What you should do is replace `mydata{k}` with `fid`. And probably `values` by `mydata{k}`.

The other bug is in `numfiles = ...`. You will always have numfiles = 5, as there are 5 characters in the '*.dat'.

```
numfiles = length(files);
```

would be better, although you would also count directories. Check one of the other questions how to solve this.